# Bounty comment gobbling text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounties

### The Problem

Writing a bounty comment will, after a text exceeds a certain length and passes down to the next line, reformat the frame and the first characters of the next lines thereafter will be wrong.

### The Tools

Windows XP SP2, Mozilla Firefox 23.0.1

### The Steps

1. **Start a Bounty**

   [image: Start a bounty]
2. **Select the *Draw Attention* button, then press *Next***

   [image: Draw Attention]
3. **The beginning frame**

   [image: Beginning frame]
4. The problem is at the left. As seen, the entrybox is stretched to the left, and the two first characters of each line are now "seemingly randomly" displayed.

   [image: The problem]

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 23.0.1 on OS X. It doesn't work when copy-pasting a lot of text into the box, it needs to be typed.

Comment: I typed all text.